# NumberFormatException: For input string: ""?

Tags: java, exception, string-parsing, numberformatexception

**Code**

```
int weight = 0;
do {
    System.out.print("Weight (lb): ");
    weight = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
    if (weight <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid weight.");
    }
} while (weight <= 0);
```

**Traceback**

```
Weight (lb): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at HealthPlan.main(HealthPlan.java:46)
```

When I run my program, I get this exception. How do I handle it?

I want to input an integer as a `weight` value. I also have to use an integer value for `height`, but my program asks for input that are `boolean`s and `character`s as well.

Someone suggested that I should use `Integer.parseInt`.

If I need to post more code, I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: Make sure the `console.nextLine()` is not an empty `String`, because the line `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` says it is...

Comment: Note : assuming `console` is a `Scanner`, you could use `console.nextInt()`.

Comment: Surround your call to `parseInt()` with a try-catch block catching this exception

Comment: Check if `console.nextLine().trim().isEmpty()` is true or not.

Comment: By the way, why the loop? This loop will never execute more than once...

Comment: @assylias I tried that, and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it simply means that you're passing an empty string into `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
String a = "";
int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only cast String into an Integer in this case.

```
Integer.parseInt("345")
```

but not in this case

```
Integer.parseInt("abc")
```

This line is giving an exception
`Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());`

Instead, Use this
`Integer.parseInt(console.nextInt());`

Comment: You can cast String to Integer, it's just that you String need to be well formatted. For example `Integer.parseInt("124")` is totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

As I did not see a solution given:

```
int weight = 0;
do {
    System.out.print("Weight (lb): ");
    String line = console.nextLine();
    if (!line.matches("-?\\d+")) { // Matches 1 or more digits
        weight = -1;
        System.out.println("Invalid weight, not a number: " + line);
    } else {
        weight = Integer.parseInt(line);
        System.out.println("Invalid weight, not positive: " + weight);
    }
} while (weight <= 0);
```

`Integer.parseInt(String)` has to be given a valid int.

Also possible is:

```
    try {
        weight = Integer.parseInt(line);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        weight = -1;
    }
```

This would also help with overflow, entering 9999999999999999.